# making list inside a list using python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I have two lists:

```
shape = [1,2,4]
board = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
```

I want to assign the board index to the shape index using a for loop so that i can put any shape size. I want the output of the shape to be `[0,0,1]`.

I have tried doing:

```
list1 = []
for x in shape:
      list1.append(board[x])
```

But the output it gives me is `[0,1,0]`.

I want the output to be `[0,0,1]`, the first three index of the board.

Comment: If you want the first 3 elements of board, why isn't `shape=[0,1,2]`?

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using

```
list1 = []
for x in shape: 
    list1.append(board[x])
```

This code means to make `list1` equal to `[board[1], board[2], board[4]]`, since you start with the empty list and then append `board[x]` for each `x` in `shape` (and since list indices start at 0 in Python).  You probably want something like

```
list1 = []
for i in xrange(len(shape)):
    list1.append(board[i])
```

Now `i` ranges from 0 to 2, as desired.

Comment: you wrote `board[1]` by mistake, i changed the 1 to i.

Comment: @yurib Thanks for fixing my typo.

Answer (score 1):

So what you mean is that the numbers in `shape` make no difference? You just want the first `len(shape)` items in `board` regardless of the numbers in `shape`?

In that case:

```
board[0:len(shape)]
```

Answer (score -1):

list indices are 0-based, the items of board at indices [1,2,4] are infact [0,1,0].
if you want to use 1-based indices you need to adjust them:

```
 list1 = [board[i-1] for i in shape]
```

Comment: >>> shape = [1,2,4]
>>> board = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
>>> list1 = [board[i-1] for i in shape]
>>> list1
[0, 0, 0]

Comment: This code would not produce `[0, 0, 1]`, which the OP is looking for.  Instead, it would produce `[0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: [0,0,0] are the values at the specified indices, that's not my fault. do you want the output to be [0,0,1] regardless of the data you have?!

Comment: @yurib The OP specifically asked for "the output to be [0,0,1], the first three index of the board."

Comment: @AdamMihalcin that was edited in later, the original post was anything but specific, i answered the question the way i understood it.

Comment: @yurib Look at the edit history at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9286542/revisions.  Both version 1 and version 2 of the question include that exact statement, modulo whitespace.